# Fix div size when css located in two separate files

Tags: css

**GOAL:** Make green container match the height of the blue container.

[image]

My `dashboard` div class in my `Dashboard.js` file does not fit within the `100vh` I set in my `DashboardLayout.js` div class:

```js
<div className="dashboard__layout">
        <div className="dashboard__layoutLeft">
          <div className="linkspace__container">
            <button>{user[0].toUpperCase()}</button>
            <button className="add__profileButton">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="dashboard__layoutRight">
          <Header {...props} />
          {props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
.dashboard__layout {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

And here the `Dashboard.js` file and the `dashboard` class I am trying to fit within the `DashboardLayout` div:

```js
<div className="dashboard">
      <div className="dash__left">
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
      <div className="dash__middle">
        <LinkButtonTypes />
        <ContentContainer />
      </div>
      <div className="dash__right">
        <PersonalUrl />
        <PhoneMockup />
      </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.dashboard {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which height you can provide on an element, you can create different solutions.
Here is an example to create multiple columns next to each other with flexbox:

```css
      .parent {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      .top-left {
        background-color: red;
        height: 20vh;
        width: 20%;
      }

      .bottom-left {
        height: 80vh;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: green;
      }
      .right {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 80%;
        background-color: blue;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="top-left"></div>
      <div class="bottom-left"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example where you have to know the height of the red block and works with position absolute instead of flexbox:

```css
      body {
        display: flex;
      }
      .parent {
        width: 20%;
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .top-left {
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .bottom-left {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding-top: 100px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: green;
      }
      .right {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 80%;
        background-color: blue;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="top-left"></div>
      <div class="bottom-left"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course you can create as many variations depending on what value you want to pass ass height.

Edit:
a last variant where you give the blue section content:

```css
      body {
        display: flex;
      }
      .parent {
        width: 20%;
        position: relative;
      }

      .top-left {
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .bottom-left {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding-top: 100px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: green;
      }
      .right {
        width: 80%;
        background-color: blue;
        font-size: 50px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="top-left"></div>
      <div class="bottom-left"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nulla
      reprehenderit fugiat exercitationem molestias corporis. Officia quod atque
      deserunt possimus architecto enim. Aperiam earum, neque animi quis
      exercitationem cupiditate repellendus.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the style of the green div.

So I suppose that you had set both the green and blue divs with `height: 100%;` which make them have the same height. But you didn't count the height of the red one in.

Just like the code

```html
<div class="dashboard-layout">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Both `left` and `right` has `height: 100%;` and so are the `blue` and the `green`. So that the height of the `red` is not counted. This leads to the overflow of the green, even its height is the same as blue because the total height now is `red + dashboard-layout`.

The easiest way to solve this problem is to set `overflow-y: hidden;` to the `dashboard-layout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this dynamically by adding the height of your Blue div and minus the height of your Red div and apply it to your Green Div.
Like this:

```js
var redHeight = document.getElementById("red").offsetHeight;
var whiteHeight = document.getElementById("white").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("blue").style.height= (redHeight - whiteHeight + "px")
```

```css
#red{
  height:200px;
  background-color:red
}
#white{
  height:50px;
}
#blue{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="red">red</div>
<div id="white">white</div>
<div id="blue">blue</div>
```